# ReactDOM rendered component after removing it does not render component again

Tags: javascript, jquery, reactjs

For a client, I am implementing a React lead form component in their non-React website.

They use a popup/modal element looking like this:

```
<div class="modal js-modal">
   <div class="modal__inner js-modal-inner">
      <div class="modal__body js-modal-body" id="modal_body">
        <!-- Content is rendered in here -->
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Their way of using this modal is as follows:

- The modal is rendered by PHP to the page.
- When something has to be shown in the modal, they render content with javascript in the `#modal_body` element.
- Then they change the `js-modal` display style to "block" to show it.

When the modal needs to **disappear** it works as follows:

- They change the `.js-modal` display style to "none"
- They remove the html inside the `#modal_body` element.

For my temporary React implementation I use the ReactDOM [render()](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#render) method to insert a React component inside `#modal_body` element.

```
// jQuery event handler when clicking a button to show something in modal
$(document).on("click", ".js-popup-form", function () {

   // Changes display style to "block"
   showModal();
   
   // Render React lead form component in modal body
   ReactDOM.render(<LeadForm />, document.getElementById("modal_body"));
});
```

**The Problem**

This approach works the **first** time, but the problem occurs after hiding the modal and removing the html from the `#modal_body` element. The second time opening the modal, the lead form component does not get rendered again.

Answer (score 0):

I had to [unmount the node](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-dom.html#unmountcomponentatnode) from the dom before removing the HTML as follows:

```
const node = document.getElementById("model_body");

// To render
ReactDOM.render(<LeadForm/>, node);

// To remove
ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(node);
```